Is lying in an subject access request (SAR) response a crime?
Is it a crime to lie on a subject access request (SAR) response?
To construct a hypothetical situation to illustrate what I mean, suppose the reality is:

Alice the individual interacts with Bob the business who acts as data controller for her data
Bob makes an error in the data processing such that there is a technical breach of the GDPR, as probably happens frequently and is minimally (but non-zero) impactful.
Alice makes a subject access request for all the personal data being held by Bob (Data X), and also information regarding article 15.2 (safeguards pursuant to Article 46 regarding transfer to a third country) (Data Y)
Bob replies within 1 month, providing a subset of X and claiming that X is complete (Lie A) and they require further time to provide Y when actually they have all the data (Lie B).  The incentive for the lies is that the data proves the technical breach and they want an extra 60 days to deal with the IT and PR issues.
Bob replies within 3 months, and the reply demonstrates the above lies.
The two month delay has a potential effect upon Alice's ability to effectively trace the extent of the data breach, perhaps because the logs of a data processor were only kept for two months.

Is there any crime that Bob may be guilty of that they would not be had they provided the exact same data, but been more general in their descriptions?
For example, if you compare the above reality to one where they gave nothing in the first month citing "things" but the same in the third month would there be extra crimes from the lie?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Article 84 requires each member state to handle penalties other than the administrative fines laid down in the GDPR itself, and to notify the EU.
Since you talk about Bob as "they," Bob is presumably a company. The question becomes one of corporate criminal liability vs personal criminal liability of Bob's employees. They may be liable if they acted to enrich themselves by hiding mistakes from their superiors, while UK corporate liability seems to require a "controlling mind" in the corporations. So the answer depends on who ordered what (and if that can be proven).
